# Proof in analysis

Tags: analysis

Suppose there is a set $A := \{a \in \mathbb{R} \ s.t.\ a < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}\}  $.

How can we prove that $a \leq 0$?

Currently, I am trying to prove by contradiction. I am starting off by assuming that $a \gt 0$ . I aim to reach a statement that contradicts the Completeness Axiom. But I am currently stuck.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Did you try to prove by contradiction?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to prove by contradiction. So I am starting off by assuming that $a > 0$. And I hope that I reach a statement that contradicts the Completeness Axiom. But I am currently stuck.

Comment: If you can use the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$, then there is always a $q\in \mathbb Q$ so that $0< q<a$.

Comment: That is a really nice way of proving this.

Answer (score 1):

If $a > 0$ is real, then there is a positive rational number smaller than $a$ (for example by density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a>0$ and then look at $\frac 1a$.  by the Archimedean Property of the reals, we can choose some integer $n>\frac 1a$.  But then $$0<\frac 1n<a$$

If you want to use the Completeness Axiom directly, suppose that there is no integer greater than $\frac 1a$.  It would follow that the sequence of natural numbers was bounded above, hence it would have a least upper bound $K$.  But then $K-1$ is not an upper bound so there is an integer $m>K-1$, whence $m+1>K$, a contradiction.